# MySQL MATCH wildcard at the beginning of a keyword

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have to look for keywords in 2 different columns, so I decided to try the mysql `MATCH` command. But if I try to search for "bcd":

```
$sql = "SELECT id,type,size,description FROM products 
WHERE MATCH (title,description) AGAINST ('+*bcd*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
```

The `MATCH` will find `bcdef`, but not `abcde`. It somehow doesn't accept the wildcard at the beginning of the keyword.

**Is there a way to apply wildcards to the beginning of a match keyword?** Or would it be better search two columns at once in a different way?

Answer (score 0):

Try that :

```
   SELECT id,type,size,description FROM products 
           WHERE title       LIKE '%bcd%' 
           Or    description LIKE '%bcd%'
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/34d5ca/2) for two keywords

Comment: if the user types in two keywords it should be possible, that one keyword is found in title and the other in description, so this wont do it...

Answer (score 0):

Use **`mysqli prepared statements`** since mysql_* is deprecated in recent PHP versions. Also in case of your query, simply use `LIKE %%` with an `OR` to search the string in multiple columns

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$string = "bcd";    

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id,type,size,description FROM products 
                         WHERE (title LIKE '%?%' OR description LIKE '%?%')");

$stmt->bind_param( "ss", $string, $string); 
// "ss" is a format string, each "s" means string

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($col1, $col2);
// then fetch and close the statement
```